# Transformar card em carousel quando diminuir a resolução

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, owl-carousel

Possuo o seguinte sistema de cards feito com `bootstrap 4`, cada um ocupando **4 colunas.**

[image: Cards]

Porém eu preciso que quando eles forem para o mobile eles virem um `Carousel`, estou tentando utilizar o [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html), porém preciso que ele verifique se a resolução é small e exibe o `Carousel` somente se for, se não, exibe os cards normais.

O problema é que eu não sei como posso fazer para ele verificar a resolução e sumir o elemento conforme ela.

Tentei utilizar a classe `d-none d-sm-block`, ela até some os `cards` quando e mobile, porém preciso que quando não for ela suma o `Carousel`.

```css
.solucoes-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.solucoes-box:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.solucoes-box .solucoes-ico {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #004398;
}

.solucoes-box .icone-solucoes {
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">Vamos além!
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
                Silvio Santos Ipsum mah  a porta da esperanaam. Ma no existem mulher feiam, existem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">Mah oee
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
                Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum  muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar textuans ha.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">texto
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
                Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum  muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar textuans ha.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">Olha o aviazino
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
                Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum  muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar textuans ha.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">Mahoeee
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
               Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum  muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar textuans ha.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="solucoes-box">
            <div class="solucoes-ico">
              <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="solucoes-content">
              <h2 class="s-titulo">Quem quer dinheiro
              </h2>
              <p class="s-descricao text-center">
                Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum  muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar textuans ha.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

### EDIT

Consegui fazer ele inserir a classe do `owl-carousel` quando a resolução for de **mobile**, porém ele não esta ficando centrado na tela como deve ser, esta todo bagunçado.

Comment: Creio que isso só seja possível fazendo uso de **Javascript**.

Comment: O que eu pensei foi usar o `outerWidth()` e adicionar ou remover a classe quando a resolução for menor que **767**, porém não to conseguindo fazer.

Comment: @LeAndrade No caso eu consegui adicionar a classe `owl-carousel` quando a resolução é menor que **768** o problema é que não consigo estilizar o carousel para ele ocupar toda a largura e altura da div.

Comment: Se já chegou até aí, edite a pergunta e coloque o código com o carousel funcionando.

Comment: Cara de mais detalhes de como esta e como vc gostaria que fique, qual div quer colocar o carrossel etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu tentei fazer adicionando as classes owl-carousel e owl-theme por jQuery quando a tela fosse menor que 768px, mas não deu muito certo... Então basicamente eu tive que replicar o conteúdo e usar `d-none d-md-block` e `d-block d-md-none` para mostrar e esconder o Owl Carrossel ou o Grid mostrando todos os itens como está na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código referente a imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

 <style>
  .solucoes-box {
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 4.5rem;
   margin-bottom: 3rem;
   transition: all 500ms ease;
  }

  .solucoes-box:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .solucoes-box .solucoes-ico {
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   color: #004398;
   text-align: center;
  }

  .solucoes-box .icone-solucoes {
   transition: all 500ms ease;
   font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .solucoes-box h2 {
   text-align: center;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container d-none d-md-block">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">Vamos além!
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum mah a porta da esperanaam. Ma no existem mulher feiam, existem.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">Mah oee
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
       textuans ha.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">texto
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
       textuans ha.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">Olha o aviazino
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
       textuans ha.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">Mahoeee
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
       textuans ha.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="solucoes-box">
     <div class="solucoes-ico">
      <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
     </div>
     <div class="solucoes-content">
      <h2 class="s-titulo">Quem quer dinheiro
      </h2>
      <p class="s-descricao text-center">
       Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
       textuans ha.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div class="container d-block d-md-none">
  <div class="row ">

   <div class="col-12 owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">Vamos além!
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum mah a porta da esperanaam. Ma no existem mulher feiam, existem.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">Mah oee
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
        textuans ha.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">texto
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
        textuans ha.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">Olha o aviazino
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
        textuans ha.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">Mahoeee
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
        textuans ha.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto item">
     <div class="solucoes-box">
      <div class="solucoes-ico">
       <span class="icone-solucoes"><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="solucoes-content">
       <h2 class="s-titulo">Quem quer dinheiro
       </h2>
       <p class="s-descricao text-center">
        Silvio Santos Ipsum ma vai pra l. Ma o Silvio Santos Ipsum muitoam interesanteam. Com ele ma voc vai gerar
        textuans ha.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   margin: 10,
   nav: true,
   responsive: {
    0: {
     items: 1
    }
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Eu fiz utilizando o Jquery para verificar o tamanho da tela com `outerWidth` quando ela é menor que 767 eu dou um addClass na div do carousel, acho que essa não é a melhor maneira mas funcionou

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti sim funciona dessa forma, mas lembre-se de tb dar o `removeClass` caso a tela volte a crescer.... Eu até tinha feito um teste tb com jQuery, mas não tinha gostado do resultado... ai prefiri fazer apenas com as classes nativas do Bootstrap e CSS

Comment: Sim eu dei um remove, ainda fiz mais algumas coisas com essa função. Funcionou legal com essa abordagem.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti massa! Essa forma que eu fiz não é muito semântica pq ela de certa forma duplica o conteúdo... então se vc consegue adicionar e remover a classe no resize é uma boa ideia sim!